# Display only one element with each class inside a div and count them

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, counting

I have a div named "items" and inside it I have some other divs with other classes (.itema, .itemb, .itemc, etc) and I want to display only one element with each div and count them (only the ones that still on the "items" div).

I tried to use the following code to count them... but didn't worked:

```
var na = $('#items.itema').size();
$('.itema').append(' x ', na);

var nb = $('#items.itemb').size();
$('.itemb').append(' x ', nb);
```

There's my fail try: http://jsfiddle.net/g32gH/

Comment: You will have to recalculate it whenever an item is moved across.

Answer (score 0):

`#items.itema` selects the element with an `id` of `items` and a class of `itema`. You want to select all elements inside of `#items` with a class of `itema`, which is done with the descendant combinator (a space):

```
#items .itema
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g32gH/3/**

Comment: But if you move it to the .other div, the counter still at 3 instead the new value (2).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code to:

```
var na = $('#items .itema').size();
$('.itema').append(' x ', na);

var nb = $('#items .itemb').size();
$('.itemb').append(' x ', nb);
```

Here's the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leniel/g32gH/12/

---

Now I see that you're using [jQuery UI Sortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable) component. I think you want something like this:

```
$("#items").sortable({
    connectWith: "#other"
});

$("#other").sortable({
    connectWith: "#items"
});   

$("#other, #items").on("sortreceive", function(event, ui)
{
    var na = $('#items .itema').size();
    $('.itema').html('itema X ' + na);

    var nb = $('#items .itemb').size();
    $('.itemb').html('itemb X ' + nb);  
});
```

Here's the JS Bin demo: http://jsbin.com/ixowed/1/edit

Comment: It only solves a part of the problem, like the other comment.

Comment: Check the jsFiddle... if it's not what you want, could you please elaborate your question better?

Comment: I did, but if you move on element to the other div, the counter doesn't updates.

Comment: Well... I moved 1 itemb to the `other` div and the count updated to 2.

Comment: Yeah, but only if you "move" on the code, not if you move by dragging.

Comment: ohhh... OK... now I got what you want! Wasn't considering the draggable nature.

Comment: I seen the update u made. It really solved the counter updating problem. Thanks a lot. Any ideia about display only one item for each class?

Comment: Only 1 item for each class... I don't understand what you want. Can you elaborate?

Comment: In example, the div #items have 3 .itema divs, but I just want to display 1. If 1 is moved to #other div, the div #items will have 2 .itema divs and still display only 1 .itema div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var items = new Array();
    $('#items p').each(function(i,element){

      items[$(element).attr('class')]++;
    });
    $(items).each(function(clas,count){
      $(clas).hide();
      $(clas).first().show().append(' X '+count);
    });
 });
```